# Check & extract keyword with regex from pastebin.com

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a date when expire pastebin post with python regex, my actual code :

```
#time_expired = re.compile('''title="When this paste gets automatically deleted"> (.*)
#           </div>''')

time_expired = re.compile('''title="When this paste gets automatically deleted">(.*)</div>''', re.DOTALL)

def pastebin_check(pastebin_link):
        br = Browser()
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cj)
        br.set_handle_equiv(True)
        br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        br.set_handle_referer(True)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101')]
        response = br.open(pastebin_link)
        html = response.read()

        print time_expired.search(html).group(1)
```

With the first (commented out) regex work, with second return large output need only 'Never', how can I repair my regex?

Comment: Add the sample text on which you are going to apply regex!

Comment: Also, please show what you're hoping to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a non-eager regexp `(.*?)`:

```
time_expired = re.compile('''title="When this paste gets automatically deleted">(.*?)</div>''', re.DOTALL) 
#notice the .*?
```

When using `.*?` the `re` engine will try to catch as little as possible and you won't get the large input. (the last `</div>`)